# Saving data internally in Android messes up my data

Tags: android, storage, hashtable, internal, gomoku

I'm currently working on a game, where I need to create a transposition table for my AI. I implemented [`Hashtable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) so that the `key` to the Hashtable is a state under consideration and its corresponding `value` is the optimal next move.

However, when I save the Hashtable in Android's internal storage and restore it next time, it seems to have some saved data, but the `keys` (i.e. game states) are different than the `keys` I have saved in the previous instance.

Here is how I save and restore my data:

```
    private void readTranspositionTableFromFile() {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        transpositionTable = (Hashtable<BoardState, NextMove>) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        deleteFile(FILENAME);
    }

    private void writeTranspositionTableToFile() {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(transpositionTable);
        oos.close();
    }
```

I see no problem in my `hashCode()` implementation, since it keeps returning same values for same states over and over.

I suspect saving/restoring the transposition table messes up my data because I logged the 2 runtimes and on the first one I got `hashCode()` to return 3964 and 3029 for the 2 states that were to be added to the table. However, while reading the table from file, the `hashCode()` returned 9119 twice.

Is there any problem in saving/restoring the data?

Comment: Maybe BoardState isn't correctly serialized? Have you verified that its members are correct after writing and reading to file?

Comment: You implemented your Hashtable yourself? Why aren't you using HashMap? I never had serialization issues with it. Please add some code of the serialization process.

Comment: @ekholm I just added `implements Serializable` to BoardState. Apart from that, my Board state just consists of few instance variables, getters, setters, hashCode() and equals().

@Martze No, I used the [Hashtable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) from Java library (java.util.Hashtable). I haven't tried HashMap.

Comment: Is that the correct way to serialize?

Comment: For debugging, I would try writing a few BoardState objects one by one to an ObjectOutputStream, reading each object back with an ObjectInputStream, and verify that all fields are correct

Comment: @ekholm I tried doing what you suggested the returned BoardState objects matched.

Comment: @sk1ll3r Ok, so I suppose hashCode() returns the same value before and after serialization? Well, then I'm out of ideas for the moment. Have you tried the same code with Hashtables that have keys and values of other types?

Comment: @ekhohlm Yeah, `hashCode()` returns the same value before and after serialization. I also tried to save and restore `Hashtables`, but when restored, it seemed to restore the same `Hashtable` (with same key-value pairs). It is very weird, since it's running the same code, just in 2 different places (while debugging/in game).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My serializing and hashing was completely fine. My program went something like this:

1. add new key-value pair to `transpositionTable`
2. play next move
3. save `transpositionTable` to internal storage

However, after meticulous logging, I found that my `transpositionTable` changed after step 2). This was because during step 1), I used

`BoardState newKey = currentData.getBoardState();`

and saved it to my `transpositionTable`. Then in step 2), when my `currentData` changed, my `transpositionTable` changed accordingly. I tried using

`BoardState newKey = currentData.getBoardState().clone();`

but that didn't work either. Finally I had to assign each field of `currentData.getBoardState()` to `newKey` manually, which worked.